# A question about the real line and the Dirichlet function.

Tags: real-analysis, graphing-functions, real-numbers, philosophy

Though the graph of the Dirichlet function is non-drawable, I think if we have to draw it in some informal way then it will be two *complete* lines (instead of isolated points).

Here's my reasoning: there cannot be any gaps on each of the two lines, because if there are such gaps, let the $x$-coordinates of the ends of the gap be $a$ and $b$, then the existence of the gap shows that there's no rational (or irrational) number in the interval $(a, b)$, which is absurd. Hence there are no gaps, and thus the lines should be complete.

But if the graph consists of exactly two lines, then it *seems* that the function is multi-valued. I know that all my discussion so far is concerned with informal concepts that deny an explicit definition. But my question is am I correct (in some sense) and how do I understand this "dilemma"?

Comment: Couldn't you make the same argument for that there are gaps for the two lines?

Comment: you are talking of the http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletFunction.html .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this boils down to is that you (and, given certain metaphysical assumptions, the universe) can't tell by looking at a line if there  is a single point removed. It follows that you can't tell if a finite number of points have been removed, as so by taking limits you can't tell if countably many points have been removed. But just because you can't tell the difference between two lines doesn't mean they are the same. The graph of the dirchlet function is **not** two horizontal lines, and the function is **not** multivalued.

Your faulty logic lies in the assumption that something necessarily *is* what is *looks like* the second paragraph is about something that *looks like* a line. The third paragraph is about something that *is* a line.

Comment: But this leads to new inconsistencies. Since people can't tell from a graph whether a line is really complete, can't I just draw a straight line and say that it's a *rational line* and none of its points represent irrational numbers? Then how can you say whether a real line *is* a real line?

Comment: Visually can't. But I don't know why it's so important to you what you can visually tell. Visually you can't tell the difference between $9^{9^9}$ and $9^{9^{9^9}}$ but that doesn't mean they are no *in fact* different.

Comment: @YuxiaoXie and yes, that's how we graph the rationals. We draw a line and say it's the rationals. Our diagrams are not mathematics. Out diagrams are things that help us understand mathematics. I can draw a circle and say it's a $1000$-gon and there's no problem, no contradiction. It's just a visual aid.

Comment: You mean, these graphs/diagrams are excluded from mathematics? So whether the line is a rational line or a real line doesn't matter to mathematicians?

Comment: Yes. Any physical representation of an object is a representation of a mathematical concept, not an actual mathematical concept.

Comment: If it is, *in fact* a rational line that matters. But there's a big difference between what is, *in fact* true vs what it *looks like*